# How to delete spaces in my access reports?

Tags: microsoft-access

my report adds two fields together but the first field has spaces in it and puts a big space in my report. I have be going to each field and back spacing all the blank spaces. this takes a long time with over 100 reports to print.

Answer (score 1):

When you say adding 2 fields, are you concatenating text? Either the way, if the issue is with white space in each field or the concatenated field then you can use [TRIM()](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/string/trim.php)